# With function in Coffee Script

Tags: coffeescript

Is the following code possible to coffee script?

```
With pex
  .simpleObject = {}
  .explicitFunction = ()->
     alert "Hello world!"
  .CONSTANTPI = 3.16
Endwith
```

Please disregard contents inside `with`. I am just referring how to do that in coffee script? instead of repeatedly typing the word `pex.`

Answer (score 3):

As JavaScript's `with` statement should not be used, it's better to implement it with nested function and `this` accessor:

```
_with = (object, block) -> block.call object

_with pex, ->
  @simpleObject = {}
  @explicitFunction = ()->
    alert "Hello world!"
  @CONSTANTPI = 3.16
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write a little helper function, since your goal seems to be assigning properties to an object, this one should suffice:

```
addprops = (obj, addthis) ->
  for own key,value of addthis
    obj[key] = value

pex = {}

addprops pex,
  simpleObject:     {}
  explicitFunction: ()->
    alert "Hello world!"
  CONSTANTPI:       3.16

console.log pex

###
OUTPUT:
{ simpleObject: {},
  explicitFunction: [Function],
  CONSTANTPI: 3.16 }
###
```

You also could have a look at one of the several [mixin libraries](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=mixin) out there.

Comment: `for key of addthis then if addthis.hasOwnProperty(key) then ...` can be written `for own key of addthis then ...`